# Can you use java and php in the same netbeans project?

Tags: java, php, netbeans

Can you run java files and php files in the same netbeans project?

If you can't, is there a similar concept to visual studio's solution - where you can have different projects written in different languages in the same solution?

Comment: I don't do Netbeans, so I can't tell much about it, just want to let you know that it's definitely possible with Eclipse.

Comment: I'd wager the reason why you can have projects in different languages in .NET solutions is because they are all supported by the CLR. And it's a completely different thing for stuff outside .NET. Not that it may not be possible though, just different things.

Comment: What's the point of this? Why wouldn't you just use Java + [servlets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet)/[JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages)?

Comment: @matt maybe he is doing php web deleopment with some Applets in it ?

Comment: Doing a php website with java tests.  Can't change the technology stack as it's legacy code...

Comment: Could always do the test in php but would prefer not to if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes it is possible. For example, you can create a maven project containing both Java and PHP files. Then, you would set-up your pom.xml to generate multiple artifacts: some for your .jar or .war deliveries files and some for your PHP deliveries. You could also implement maven modules under a parent pom.xml if you are dealing with a big project.